# I typed () in terminal and got a prompt. What is it for?

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

I typed `()` in Terminal and got a prompt:

```
function>
```

I can't find any zsh documentation about it (or if it is even related to zsh). I realized I can type any gibberish `anygibberish()` and also get the prompt. If you continue to type `()` at the `function>` prompt, the prompt grows:

```
function function function>
```

There are custom functions in my .zshrc file and this `function>` prompt will execute those as if I was at a standard prompt.

```
function> config
```

Built-in functions work at the prompt as well:

```
function> ls -a
```

What else can the `function>` prompt do?

Answer (score 5):

Zsh allows anonymous functions, which are executed right on the spot. For instance

```
() {
echo $1 $1 $1
} X Y
```

prints *X X X*. The main use in shell scripts is for having a piece of code where you want to define variables locally, without affecting the rest of your program. I don't see any pratical use for it in interactive shells, but if you do, the *function* prompt serves to remind you, that you are now inside a function definition.